# How can i insert my data in MySQL table in one column only

Tags: mysql

somethings bothering me today and its how to insert my data in my table in a specific column. I don't know how so if anyone can help me I'd really really appreciate it.

my table(holidaytype) has the fields:

```
-----------------------
|id  |type |multiplier|
| 1  |  R  |          |
| 2  |  S  |          |
```

The id and type values must not be changed but the multiplier value will be coming from an input. I don't know what query should I be doing to do this.

I've tried :

```
INSERT INTO holidaytype(multiplier)
SELECT multiplier  
FROM holidaytype
WHERE `type` = 'R'
```

the results says : 1 row(s) affected Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0 0.109 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`.  For example, if you wanted to make `multiplier` be 10 for type `R`, and 20 for type `S`, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = 10 WHERE `type` = 'R'
UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = 20 WHERE `type` = 'S'
```

You use `INSERT` when you want to create entire new rows in a table.  Any modifications to existing rows is done through `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: thanks it worked great but can I ask you 1 more thing how would I change it when multiplier depends on an input.

Comment: You can join with other tables like this, for example:  `UPDATE holidaytype, inputtable SET multiplier = inputtable.value WHERE holidaytype.type = inputtable.type`

Comment: Ahh get it. Another question what if my type has 2 text boxes each 1 for R and 1 for S and those are for the multipliers For example (R = 1.4 and S = 1.7)how would i update them? since they have to match the type.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking something like this;

```
UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = yourvalue WHERE TYPE = 'R'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for update statement

```
UPDATE holidaytype SET multiplier = value WHERE type = 'R'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Update for it. Because if you use Insert then values are inserted in all columns of table and if you not provide any value than null is inserted in the remaining columns
try Update Query for It,

```
UPDATE holidaytype 
  SET multiplier = yourvalue WHERE type = 'R'
```